# Detail View Controller from Table View Controller WITHOUT Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `tableview` in a controller that shows receipts and their image, date created, etc.
I made it so when the user taps a cell, it goes to `DetailViewController`.  Using this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    ReceiptDetailViewController *controller = [[ReceiptDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReceiptDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I'd like to pass the image, date, category, etc, to my new view in a `UIImageView`, `textView`, etc.
This is the code for my Table in the first controller:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    Receipt *receipt = [self.receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ReceiptCategory *category = receipt.relationshipToCategory;
    ReceiptImage *image = receipt.relationshipToImage;

    cell.textLabel.text = category.receiptCategory;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = receipt.date.description;

    if(self.imageCache.count <= indexPath.row) {
        [self.imageCache addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:image.data]];
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    imageView.image = [self.imageCache objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = imageView.image;

    return cell;
}
```

How do I pass this data?  I have searched around for two days now and all solutions include a storyboard, which I am not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get reference to your receipt in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and pass it to ReceiptDetailViewController. I assume you have property to accept the data in ReceiptDetailViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Get reference to receipt
    Receipt *receipt = [self.receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ReceiptDetailViewController *controller = [[ReceiptDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReceiptDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Pass data to controller
    controller.receipt = receipt;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

It this example you should create property in ReceiptDetailViewController.h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) Receipt *receipt;
```

Now you can use it in your ReceiptDetailViewController object.

Comment: You have to add this line to ReceiptDetailViewController.h @property(nonatomic, strong) Receipt *receipt; What do you mean that you try to add @property but it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for taking the time to help me out, it's much appreciated.  I added '@property(nonatomic, strong) Receipt *receipt;
' into the header file of my detailviewcontroller but it returns two errors - Unknown type name 'Receipt', and 'Property with retain or strong attribute must be of object type'.  I apologize if this is a silly question, but how would I solve these issues?  Thanks

Comment: Add #import "Receipt.h" to the top of the same file. It should help.

Comment: It did help, thanks a lot, now there aren't any issues in Xcode :) However, when I run the app on my iPhone and tap a cell (hoping to take me to DetailViewController with a blank UITextView and UIImageView at the moment), it crashes :S

Comment: Post your error and code from viewDidLoad/viewDidAppeare if implemented.

Comment: D'oh!  I made a little embarrassing mistake that I've now deleted - thanks so much for your help!  I really appreciate it.  :)  Just a quick question, how do I reference 'image' to display in my UIImageView called 'imageView' in ReceiptDetailViewController?  Again, I have researched this but all use storyboards and segues!

Comment: You can add line in viewDidLoad: imageView.image = YOURUIIMAGE; it should do the job.

Comment: I added viewDidLoad: imageView.image = image;, because 'image' is the variable of the image in the TableView.  However, it is not showing anything at all, the UIImageView in my DetailViewController is blank.  I tried viewDidLoad: imageView.image = receipt.RelationshipToImage but that didn't work either. :S

Comment: As far as I see you have to do the same as in cellForRow..  imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:receipt.RelationshipToImage.data]

Answer (score 0):

You should just use Table View Delegate Method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

There you can retrieve the selected receipt and pass the data to the detail view like that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    ReceiptDetailViewController *controller = [[ReceiptDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReceiptDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    Receipt *selectedReceipt = [self.receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    controller.receipt = selectedReceipt;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class for your detailed view controller and create an object of the same when the user clicks on any cell.
Something like this

```
DetailViewControllerClass *newObject = [[DetailViewControllerClass alloc] init];
newObject.data1 = dataToBeSent ; //assign data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You should make an object of Receipt in ReceiptDetailViewController and make the property nonatomic and strong Than in tour view controller Write this

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Receipt *receipt = [self.receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 ReceiptDetailViewController *controller = [[ReceiptDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReceiptDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
controller.objReceipt= receipt;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```