# Calculate Average Amount from a Date to Date? (For past week, month, etc.)?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate, average

I'm using CoreData to save two things - `amount` spent and `date`.  How do I calculate the average for all `amount` entries when the `date` is from the current date to the last 7 days?

I've searched everywhere for a tutorial but it's very difficult to search with the right keywords.  I assume `for` is required, for 'current date to [current date - 6]' or something.

To make things clearer, here's my amount and date:

- `self.receipt.amount`
- `self.receipt.date.description`

So basicaly, the average `amount` spent over the last week.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you have a collection with all the receipts??

Comment: @Calleth'Zion' Hi, thanks for replying, what do you mean a collection?

Comment: a list of all the receipts...

Comment: Sorry if I'm sounding a bit silly, but I have a TableViewViewController that has a tableview that displays all the receipts.  You can see my code for this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626119/detail-view-controller-from-table-view-controller-without-storyboard Please forgive me if I haven't provided the correct details, I'm really new to iOS development and am just trying out a few things :)

Comment: ok your list is called receiptsArray, well it could be a hardcode but i suggest to get the las 7 days and iterate all your receipts in these seven days, if date inside u add the amount to a counter, at the end of the iteration you calculate the average....

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks!  I'll give it a go

Comment: that isnt too hard if it is just the last 7 days... but if after that you will need to add last five years (i mean a lot of time) then yeap, u will need a better way to have it done...

Comment: Yep definitely.  I just have to research how to refer to the amounts that fall in a specified date range.  :)  Thanks for your help!